# Golang number base conversion

Tags: go, base-conversion

I was wondering, how do you convert a base10 number from one base to another without usage of `strconv` in Golang ?

Could you please give me some advice ?

Comment: so what's the background that you don't want to use `strconv` ?

Comment: of course you can do something like this: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wddPLH0U3c), but I don't this this is what you want.

Comment: I used `strconv` at first, but after studying task i found out that the requirements were not to use this package

Comment: and i dont't want to end up with bunch of if else like https://golang.org/src/strconv/itoa.go?s=628:668#L60

Comment: The radix is only relevant to the string representation, so why not use strconv to do it? Otherwise you are just going to be implementing the functions from strconv yourself. (BTW, did you read the source if itoa.go? The if else chain, which isn't very long at 3 blocks, is only there for optimizations.)

Comment: @Elmor, check if you like my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363847/1652408)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [math](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Log) package and a log [identify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base):

log_77(x) = log(x) / log(77)

Answer (score 9):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(big.NewInt(1000000000000).Text(62))
}
```

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/I2YIjfIXO9L)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably cheating but I guess you could look at the implementation of [strconv.FormatInt](https://golang.org/src/strconv/itoa.go?s=628:668#L8), and build some of your own code using that as an example. That way you aren't using it directly, you have implemented it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to convert any decimal number to any base with the character set of your choice.

```
func encode(nb uint64, buf *bytes.Buffer, base string) {
  l := uint64(len(base))
  if nb/l != 0 {
    encode(nb/l, buf, base)
  }
  buf.WriteByte(base[nb%l])
}

func decode(enc, base string) uint64 {
  var nb uint64
  lbase := len(base)
  le := len(enc)
  for i := 0; i < le; i++ {
    mult := 1
    for j := 0; j < le-i-1; j++ {
        mult *= lbase
    }
    nb += uint64(strings.IndexByte(base, enc[i]) * mult)
  }
  return nb
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
// encoding
var buf bytes.Buffer
encode(100, &buf, "0123456789abcdef")
fmt.Println(buf.String())
// 64

// decoding
val := decode("64", "0123456789abcdef")
fmt.Println(val)
// 100
```